# Proof of identity A = A or 1 = 1

Tags: equivalence-relations, axioms, philosophy

Is 1 = 1 an assumption? I feel it's a very good assumption, but is there a proof for it? Imagine a world where people were contesting it, where equivalence wasn't a common sense concept. In reality no 2 things are exactly equivalent because even comparing an object to itself would least differ in temporal location, but in our minds we have the concept of perfect equivalence. Ask yourself, what if 1 ~ 1

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it is an assumption, like every math prook ends when you came to "those things are/aren't equal so..." (strictly speaking) so I can't figure how this could be proved itself. Btw I even think you can construct other mathematics without this assumption but they wouldn't be such prolific...

Comment: $1=1$ is so obviously true, that a discussion over the possibility, that it is false, is extremely philosophical.

Comment: If $1\approx 1$, then where is the difference between "them"?

Comment: @James: You might know extensionally that two objects are not equal, but intentionally you will not be able to "explain why". Namely, maybe two objects satisfy all the same properties (except equality), so within the universe you cannot discern them; but you do know they are not the same object.

Answer (score 2):

In most ways to formalize logic with equality, "$t=t$" is an *axiom* for every expression (or "term", in the jargon of logic) $t$.

In other words, the validity of the claim $t=t$ is part of the conventions about what the symbol $=$ *means*. It's not really about any deep or philosophical truth -- simply an agreement among mathematicians that if you want to think about a relation that does *not* relate everything to itself, you're free to do so, but you must not use the $=$ symbol to write it (on pain of confusing everyone you speak to).

[IEEE-754 NaN comparisons nonwithstanding].